# .NET Routing match all pattern (wildcard) with exceptions

Tags: .net-3.5, routes

If say I have a route that is defined like this: `"{books}/{*all}"`, then any URL that have a root folder defined will match it (i.e. http://mysite.com/greekbooks/somethingirrelavant.htm).

But what if I wanted to go further, and would like to present a custom handler for greekbooks published in 1982 (i.e. the url http://mysite.com/greekbooks/1982/anythinghere). I would really **not like** to put this logic into my first route handler, but to present a second one to deals with serving pages when this url is matched.

The problem is that `"{books}/{*all}"` will eat `"{books}/1982/{*all}"` also.

Basically how do you define more than one route handler when dealing with `'*' ( all )` match? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by controlling the order that the routes are defined because a URL is evaluated against routes in the order that they are added to the Routes collection.

Here are the rules for how Routes are processed...

> 1. The route patterns that you have defined or the default route
>      patterns, if any, that are included
>      in your project type.
> 2. The order in which you added them to the Routes collection.
> 3. Any default values that you have provided for a route.
> 4. Any constraints that you have provided for a route.
> 5. Whether you have defined routing to handle requests that match a
>      physical file.
>
> [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You would put your additional

```
{book}/{year}/{*all}
```

catch first. I would go one step further and suggest that you add a constraint to the {book}/{year}/{*all} route so that it is only numeric.